# How to make loop move on to another loop once the first loop is done

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I just want to know the logic within this problem. I just want my program to execute another loops once the first loop was done.

```
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        print(i*j,end="\t")
    print("\n")
```

After the code above was done I want my program to perform another loop which is this one:

```
for i in range(5,1,-1):
    for j in range(5,1,-1):
        print(i*j,end="\t")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you saying you want to complete your first code sample, and then immediately do the next one? Because if that's the case then why not just put the second block of code immediately after the first one in your .py file? Again, I may be misunderstanding what you asked

Answer (score 1):

Just order them how you want them executed (in this case, one after the other). Python, among many other languages will just execute code sequentially unless you *specifically* introduce control structures like loops:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        print(i*j,end="\t")
    print("\n")
for i in range(5,1,-1):
    for j in range(5,1,-1):
        print(i*j,end="\t")
    print("\n")
```

---

Just be aware that the second loop isn't a perfect reversal of the first. Since ranges are inclusive at the start and exclusive at the end, the tow complementary loops would be:

```
for i in range(1,5):        # 1..4 inclusive
for i in range(4,0,-1):     # 4..1 inclusive
```

Comment: Infinity, it was your bizarre claim that being interpreted somehow gave Python the ability to execute code sequentially. Since just about every procedural language (compiled or not) has this ability (and since Python (CPython) *is* compiled, just on demand, and not to machine language), this just isn't true. I'll be happy to change that to an upvote if that erroneous information is removed, since your answer is otherwise okay.

Comment: Actually, I'll just make a *suggested* change and cancel the downvote. You can accept, modify or roll back as you see fit.

Comment: Ok. Of course I respect you changes and comments. I'm just 16, trying to gain up in Python by researching on doubts. Thank you